# distribute matrix values of a binary image

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to take the tril below and distribute the values equally so it ends up like a modified checkerboard.

```
x=ones(1186,686);
x2=tril(x);
```

A sample simplified matrix of what I need to have happen is below:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The matrix above needs to be changed into:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've tried looking for built in MATLAB functions that would evenly distribute the zeros values across the board, but have not found anything that works. In terms of the output, where the ones and zeros appear is somewhat irrelevant. They just need to be distributed as evenly as possible within the matrix.  For example the 3rd line of the modified matrix could = 1 1 1 0 1 1 or the like.

Would be be possible to achieve this effect a different way than starting with the tril that I'm not seeing?

For Beaker and anyone that wants to comment on how I could have better asked my original question.

This is the result of what I wanted.  It's not exactly what I had described, but it achieves the same function I'm after.  It's Completely different direction.  I'm doing image analysis of the mixing and segregation of particles.  Having contrived images like this allows me to determine if my mixing algorithm is producing the results I'm expecting.  I can use the interleaving code you gave to continue making new and interesting patterns (not shown).

```
img=checkerboard(1,1186,686);
img_bw=im2bw(img);
img_mix=triu(img_bw,-500);
img_neg=imcomplement(img_mix);
imshow(img_neg)
```

Comment: So you want to get the number of `1` in each row. Distribute each `1` so that every other value is a `1`. Start on the left hand side with a `1`?

Comment: How is that an even distribution of zeros? Are you asking how to go from `tril(ones(n))` to just interlacing the columns? Or... what are you actually asking?

Comment: Are you talking about a random distribution or some method to construct the matrix? What is "as evenly as possible"?

Comment: I understand that what I'm actually trying to ask is confusing which is why I tried to clarify it with the example matrices.  Still didn't come across though, sorry.  An 'even' distribution is probably the wrong word.  Like what Dan said, I'm trying to interlace the columns.  The number of ones and zeros in each row must remain constant, however their distribution needs to change and must be maximized.  For example:
A row like this:
0 0 0 1 1 1 
needs to change into this:
0 1 0 1 0 1
Not this:
0 1 1 0 0 1
Or any variation there of.

Answer (score 1):

I think this *might* be what you're after. Note that I borrowed the interleave-by-reshape trick from [this blog post](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/interleave_matrices). (I also used `triu` instead of `tril` since it matched your example.)

```
x=ones(12,10);
x2=triu(x);
[rows,cols]=size(x2);
a = x2(:,1:cols/2);
b = x2(:,end:-1:(cols/2)+1);

% interlave two same sized matrices by column
a = a.';
b = b.';
col_interleave = reshape([b(:) a(:)]',2*size(a,1), []).'
```

Output is:

```
col_interleave =

  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1
  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: It's not, but I can use it for a different part of the analysis I'm going.
Thanks!

Comment: @user3753314: If this is not what you are asking for, please explain more precisely what you want.

Comment: I've been working with the interleave function you gave.  Although it's not exactly what I wanted, I was able to modify what you gave me to get it to do exactly what I needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3753314 Could you update your question with the code you came up with? I'm kinda curious as to what you were trying to achieve.